# Using cooling to temporarily lock in deformation in plastics?

Tags: temperature, plastics

I need to shrink PEEK or solid polyimide tube, $\pu{1mm}$ wall thickness and $\pu{15mm}$ OD over another fragile component. Is it possible to stretch the tube over a mandrel, lock in the deformation using solid $\ce{CO2}$, slip over the component, then shrink by allowing temperature to rise to room temperature? Could also use acetone plus dry ice or liquid nitrogen if necessary.

Comment: Seems worth trying... see https://www.nature.com/articles/srep44936